# set of points of local invertibility of function.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^2}$ $\text{be a function given by}$ $f(x,y)=(x^3+3xy^2-15x-12xy,x+y)$. let $S$={$(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:f\; \text{is locally invertible at}(x,y)$}.Then

> 1).$S=\mathbb{R^2}$ \ $(0,0)$
>
> 2).$S$ is open in $ \mathbb{R^2}$
>
> 3).$S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R^2}$
>
> 4).$\mathbb{R^2}$\ $S$ is countable

solution i tried is

by taking the jacobian of above function

$ J = \left| \begin{align} & 3x^2+3y^2-15 & 6xy-12 \\ & 1 & 1\end{align} \right| = 3x^2+3y^2-15-6xy+12$

now i have to find the points where determinant is zero we put $3x^2+3y^2-15-6xy+12=0$

by solving it we get $(x-y)^2=1$ now we get two lines $x-y=1 \;and\;x-y=-1$

so from this we can see that the points where function is invertible is points not on these lines .

set $S=\mathbb{R^2}$ \ $(x-y)^2=1$

this set is dense so option 3 is true and option 1 is wrong also 4th is wrong.But what about option 2 ?in answer key this right option but i have no idea how this is right .

please help

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2) is right because a line in $\mathbb R^2$ is a closed set and therefore the union of two lines is a closed set. Since $S^\complement$ is closed, $S$ is an open set.

Comment: Thank you sir .

Comment: I'm glad I could help.